# Is stat.stddev from the PIL method, the correct way to calculate overall contrast of the image?

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I am attempting to calculate the average brightness and contrast of an image using the PIL method.

I was able to obtain the brightness, as follows:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageStat
im = Image.open("image.jpg")

def calculate_brightness(image):
    greyscale_image = image.convert('L')
    histogram = greyscale_image.histogram()
    pixels = sum(histogram)
    brightness = scale = len(histogram)

for index in range(0, scale):
    ratio = histogram[index] / pixels
    brightness += ratio * (-scale + index)

return 1 if brightness == 255 else brightness / scale

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for file in sys.argv[1:]:
    image = Image.open("image.jpg")
    print("%s\t%s" % (image, calculate_brightness(image)))

brightness = calculate_brightness(image)
brightness
```

Out:

```
0.44112796875000065
```

I am attempting to get contrast as follows:

```
stat= ImageStat.Stat(im)
stat.stddev
```

Out:

```
[70.14142756493554, 62.99058368255826, 67.02872362800592]
```

From my understanding the above values produce contrast for the 3 bands of an image (RBG- one for each color). So, if I average them out, would that be a good way to obtain a rough estimate of an overall contrast of the image?

I would love to hear if my reasoning and methods are correct, and if not, if there is a better way to obtain the image contrast.